# php Y-m-d add H:i:s

Tags: php, datetime

I have this code for parsing date from excel cell and post it using json

**the date on excel**

using format dd/mm/yyyy

| column G |

|13/12/2020|

**mycode**

```
//start loop excel from 2nd row. Row 1 is title row
    for ($j=2; $j < $lastRow; $j++ ){
      ...
      'mr_submit_target' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCell('G'.$j)->getValue())),
}
```

**the result**

"mr_submit_target": "1900-01-04 07:20:00", this is absolutely wrong based on excel data

**my goal**

to add H:i:s for my date from = "2020-12-13" to "2020-12-13 00:00:00"
the exact time is not very important, but the server only can post using format Y-m-d H:i:s, thats why on my code i add 'H:i:s'

Comment: Make a `strtotime(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCell('G'.$j)->getValue())` and the @user3783243 is pointing to the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should convert date string to time 
try this one

```
for ($j=2; $j < $lastRow; $j++ )
{ 
      'mr_submit_target' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCell('G'.$j)->getValue())),
}
```

I hope you got answered question | Happy coding  ;)